# Nodemon keep crashing with "already in use error"

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I am using nodemon with express.js on localserver with 8080 port.

nodemon keeps always crushing after any change I do in my files with this error:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1447:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/sergey/Dev/Web/projects/YelpCamp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sergey/Dev/Web/projects/YelpCamp/app.js:69:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1123:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 8080
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I can fix it just by adding space or enter, but nodemon will crush again after another change I will make.

My app.js listener:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, process.env.ip, function(){
    console.log('Server is running!');
});
```

Comment: looks like another app is running on port 8080. change the port number if it crashes

Comment: Still the same issue with port 3000

Comment: do you have two instances app in different modules

Comment: No. got only one app.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you running on linux you need to kill all process at 8080 (or any port you get stuck)

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)
```

Then run your application again.
I think you make some bug in your code so it's affect to you nodemon.

Comment: It didnt help me, if it was a bug why would nodemon keep working after I make spaces or enters (just any code changes)?

Comment: Strange behavior, try port 3000, but before starting node app, execute command in terminal: ```sudo fuser -k 3000/tcp```  and then start the app, look if it works

Comment: @SergeyArenzon You can adding this option "nodemon --watch <where you want to watch>"